# Mule 3.3 spring 3.1 hibernate 3.6 transaction management

Tags: spring, hibernate, mule, transactionmanager

I am working on an application which involves mule, spring, hibernate with annotations. I am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager. Now the problem is :

I have certain components in mule which logs data into db based on conditions using hibernate. I have used @Transactional which inserts few data and then commits the transaction when the method scope is completed. But the behaviour which i want is : first component inserts data based on some condition, but the transaction should not commit immediately, again my second component that is a java class should insert some data again then third etc. if any of the component fails all the queries executed in all the components should be rolled back. all of this components are separate java classes

How can i achieve such behaviour.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Let your whole component execution chain be in a transaction. then it will meet your expectation. it is easy to do it if all your components are in the same one spring appliction context. In the case, there are two things you need to do:

1. Add `@Transactional` annotation on your component class or specific methods which need to be in transaction. By default, transactional method use `REQUIRED` Propagation setting which will let all method in the exection chain merge to only one transaction.
2. Make sure Spring can scan all your components.

   @Transactional
   @Component( "lbsProviderApiCallJob" )
   public class LbsProviderApiCallJoImpl implements LbsProviderApiCallJob, ApplicationContextAware {

If all your component are not in a spring context. it is complex to make it.